# Error to Handling Remote Data with HTTPClient and JSON Titanium Android Emulator

Tags: android, titanium

I´m trying run the Titanium Appcelerator tutorial: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Handling+Remote+Data+with+HTTPClient+and+JSON

But the HTTP Request don´t work, this is the trace error:

```
I/TiAnalyticsSvc(  289): (Thread-14) [289,25871] Sending 10 analytics events.
E/TiAnalyticsSvc(  289): (Thread-14) [20264,46135] Error posting events: api.appcelerator.net
E/TiAnalyticsSvc(  289): java.net.UnknownHostException: api.appcelerator.net
E/TiAnalyticsSvc(  289):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:513)
E/TiAnalyticsSvc(  289):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:278)
E/TiAnalyticsSvc(  289):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:242)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're trying to use `api.appcelerator.net` and that doesn't exist.  The tutorial uses `https://www.appcelerator.com`

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just copy-paste this code:https://raw.github.com/appcelerator/Documentation-Examples/master/HTTPClient/Resources/app.js

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that "api.appcelerator.net" is an unknown host. I have looked at the link and can see no reference to this URL.

The example uses : "https://www.appcelerator.com";

The second code snippet uses: "https://raw.github.com/appcelerator/Documentation-Examples/master/HTTPClient/data/json.txt";

which also works. If your seeing that URL on a different page then it is clearly a mistake as it is not valid, perhaps an old one.